# LinkedIn Signin script won't work on PHP page - only HTML pages

Tags: api, authentication, linkedin-api

Part of the login script for the linkedIn API reads as follows:

```
<script type="in/Login">
Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
```

Unfortunately, when I save the page as a `.php` file, the `<?js` piece of the code is throwing an error. However, if I save the file as `.html`, there is no error and the login with linkedIn button shows up just fine.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there a way to put this button on a php page?

For reference, the error that I'm seeing reads:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<script type="in/Login">
Hello, <?php echo '<' . '?js= firstname ?' . '>' ; ?> <?php echo '<' . '?js= lastName ?' . '>' ; ?>.
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly - why wouldn't they make a php friendly demo though?

Comment: The php interpreter interprets the file, and "<?" means something to him (As you do it in <?php ...?>), so you have to escape it somehow.

Comment: Or disable php short tags and use <?php tags instead of just <?